# Can't load Windows 8 from Grub 2.0 (Ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, windows-8

Just installed dual-boot Ubuntu 13.04 on my self-built Windows 8 Pro PC, and after the installation I restarted, and once I was prompted with GRUB 2.0 I tried to boot Windows 8, and a few seconds after I selected the OS it would restart my computer entirely.

I installed Windows 8 first, and I installed Ubuntu on my 80 Gigabyte hard disk drive. I would just like to know how to either uninstall Ubuntu and Grub entirely or just boot with Windows 8 normally.

#### System Information:

**System Processor:** Intel Core Duo 6700 2.66 Ghz
**System DRAM:** 8GB DDR2 DRAM
**Graphics Processor:** Sapphire AMD 5570 1GB GDDR3
**Motherboard:** ABit AB9 Pro
**Storage:** 1TB Western Digital Caviar Green, 500GB, 80GB

Answer (score 0):

If you have a windows repair cd, this can do the trick maybe. But you won't lose your data, its just accessing the drive that a little messed up.

Answer (score 0):

In your BIOS, try disabling SecureBoot.
See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI for more information.